# Is there a way of handling Framebuffer Objects (FBO's) in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, framebuffer

I'm learning to manipulate postion values in the GPU using textures a.k.a., Framebuffer Objects (FBO's), while using Three.js. I've been using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29053870/2441384) as a starting place, and this [example](http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/webgl/particles/particles_zz85.html) by @mrdoob and @zz85, as well as this [old thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1183).

However, the examples are quite dated (examples use three.js rev.55 vs. current rev.80), so I'm needing make a fair number of revisions and reworks to the code. Before I get in too deep I wanted to pause and ask if any way of handling FBO's has already been written into the Three.js code base, or if I've overlooked an updated script somewhere. Thanks!

If not, I'll do my darnedest and perhaps post the result here if it seems generally useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you like to "pop the hood", I wanted to share an absolutely minimal example of a FBO scene in THREE.js. Hopefully the inline comments help spell out how this comes together:

```js
// specify the container where we'll render the scene
var elem = document.querySelector('body'),
    elemW = elem.clientWidth,
    elemH = elem.clientHeight

// generate a scene object
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// generate a camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, elemW/elemH, 0.001, 100);

// generate a renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(elemW, elemH);
elem.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// generate controls
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// position camera and controls
camera.position.set(0.5, 0.5, -5);
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0);

/**
* FBO
**/

// verify browser agent supports "frame buffer object" features
gl = renderer.getContext();
if (!gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float') ||
     gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS) == 0) {
  alert(' * Cannot create FBO :(');
}

// set initial positions of `w*h` particles
var w = h = 256,
    i = 0,
    data = new Float32Array(w*h*3);
for (var x=0; x<w; x++) {
  for (var y=0; y<h; y++) {
    data[i++] = x/w;
    data[i++] = y/h;
    data[i++] = 0;
  }
}

// feed those positions into a data texture
var dataTex = new THREE.DataTexture(data, w, h, THREE.RGBFormat, THREE.FloatType);
dataTex.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
dataTex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
dataTex.needsUpdate = true;

// add the data texture with positions to a material for the simulation
var simMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: { posTex: { type: 't', value: dataTex }, },
  vertexShader: document.querySelector('#sim-vs').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.querySelector('#sim-fs').textContent,
});

// delete dataTex; it isn't used after initializing point positions
delete dataTex;

THREE.FBO = function(w, simMat) {
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w/2, w/2, w/2, -w/2, -1, 1);
  this.scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, w), simMat));
};

// create a scene where we'll render the positional attributes
var fbo = new THREE.FBO(w, simMaterial);

// create render targets a + b to which the simulation will be rendered
var renderTargetA = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(w, h, {
  wrapS: THREE.RepeatWrapping,
  wrapT: THREE.RepeatWrapping,
  minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
  magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
  format: THREE.RGBFormat,
  type: THREE.FloatType,
  stencilBuffer: false,
});

// a second render target lets us store input + output positional states
renderTargetB = renderTargetA.clone();

// render the positions to the render targets
renderer.render(fbo.scene, fbo.camera, renderTargetA, false);
renderer.render(fbo.scene, fbo.camera, renderTargetB, false);

// store the uv attrs; each is x,y and identifies a given point's
// position data within the positional texture; must be scaled 0:1!
var geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
    arr = new Float32Array(w*h*3);
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i++] = (i%w)/w;
  arr[i++] = Math.floor(i/w)/h;
  arr[i++] = 0;
}
geo.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(arr, 3, true))

// create material the user sees
var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    posMap: { type: 't', value: null }, // `posMap` is set each render
  },
  vertexShader: document.querySelector('#ui-vert').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.querySelector('#ui-frag').textContent,
  transparent: true,
});

// add the points the user sees to the scene
var mesh = new THREE.Points(geo, material);
scene.add(mesh);

function render() {
  // at the start of the render block, A is one frame behind B
  var oldA = renderTargetA; // store A, the penultimate state
  renderTargetA = renderTargetB; // advance A to the updated state
  renderTargetB = oldA; // set B to the penultimate state

  // pass the updated positional values to the simulation
  simMaterial.uniforms.posTex.value = renderTargetA.texture;

  // run a frame and store the new positional values in renderTargetB
  renderer.render(fbo.scene, fbo.camera, renderTargetB, false);

  // pass the new positional values to the scene users see
  material.uniforms.posMap.value = renderTargetB.texture;

  // render the scene users see as normal
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/101/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<!-- The simulation shaders update positional attributes -->
<script id='sim-vs' type='x-shader/x-vert'>
  precision mediump float;

  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

  attribute vec2 uv; // x,y offsets of each point in texture
  attribute vec3 position;

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    vUv = vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<script id='sim-fs' type='x-shader/x-frag'>
  precision mediump float;

  uniform sampler2D posTex;

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {

    // read the supplied x,y,z vert positions
    vec3 pos = texture2D(posTex, vUv).xyz;

    // update the positional attributes here!
    pos.x += cos(pos.y) / 100.0;
    pos.y += tan(pos.x) / 100.0;

    // render the new positional attributes
    gl_FragColor = vec4(pos, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<!-- The ui shaders render what the user sees -->
<script id='ui-vert' type='x-shader/x-vert'>
  precision mediump float;

  uniform sampler2D posMap; // contains positional data read from sim-fs
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

  attribute vec2 position;

  void main() {

    // read this particle's position, which is stored as a pixel color
    vec3 pos = texture2D(posMap, position.xy).xyz;

    // project this particle
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    // set the size of each particle
    gl_PointSize = 0.3 / -mvPosition.z;
  }

</script>

<script id='ui-frag' type='x-shader/x-frag'>
  precision mediump float;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.5, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that there is a way in Three.js to handle Frame Buffer Objects (FBOs) to calculate things like changing position data using the GPU; it is called the [THREE.GPUComputationRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cefe993143146ea2479fdbf3bfcf51ee1c856d83/examples/js/GPUComputationRenderer.js). There is an excellent flock of birds example [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds) that demonstrates how to pass a number of variables by rendering their values into textures to be used in the final shader.